# How to specify the version of Python for spark-submit to use?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have two versions of Python. When I launch a spark application using spark-submit, the application uses the default version of Python. But, I want to use the other one.
How to specify the version of Python for spark-submit to use?

Answer (score 23):

You can set the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable in `conf/spark-env.sh` (in Spark's installation directory) to the absolute path of the desired Python executable.

Spark distribution contains `spark-env.sh.template` (`spark-env.cmd.template` on Windows) by default. It must be renamed to `spark-env.sh` (`spark-env.cmd`) first.

For example, if Python executable is installed under `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON='/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3'
```

Check out the [configuration documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) for more information.

Comment: I tried your solution : I set ```PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/python``` in```spark-env.sh```but it doesn't work. I use spark 1.3.1

Comment: As far as I know, any environment variables should be set in the location I posted. Other parameters are added to the conf/spark-defaults.conf as key value pairs. I've changed the link in the answer to the 1.3.1 docs, which state the same as older versions. The submission script should load in both configs by default.

Comment: Hi, I used Anaconda Python distribution with Pyspark and also set PYSPARK_PYTHON in spark-env.sh and everything worked fine. Also I set it similar way in my virtualenv configuration for local tests. I used a command like this `export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/local/ml/anaconda/bin/python"`, maybe you have mistyped something?

Comment: It works for [Pyspark 2.3.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) too.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) linked in the post it says that "When running Spark on YARN in cluster mode, environment variables need to be set using the spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName] property in your conf/spark-defaults.conf file". What I did was pass `--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2` and `--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python2` as options when calling `spark-submit`. That sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 14):

In my environment I simply used

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2.7
```

It worked for me

Comment: It will work only if the path to `python2.7` is in the `PATH` environment variable. It is better to use an absolute path to the Python executable.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with that, actually forget to mention that in my answer since the PATH had already been setup for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the option `PYSPARK_MAJOR_PYTHON_VERSION` in `spark-submit` command line, you should check this:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html

You can search `spark.kubernetes.pyspark.pythonVersion` in this page and you'll find following content:

```
spark.kubernetes.pyspark.pythonVersion  "2" This sets the major Python version of the docker image used to run the driver and executor containers. Can either be 2 or 3.
```

Now, your command should looks like :

```
spark-submit --conf spark.kubernetes.pyspark.pythonVersion=3 ...
```

It should work.

Answer (score -3):

You can either specify the version of Python by listing the path to your install in a shebang line in your script:

myfile.py:

```
#!/full/path/to/specific/python2.7
```

or by calling it on the command line without a shebang line in your script:

```
/full/path/to/specific/python2.7 myfile.py
```

However, I'd recommend looking into Python's excellent virtual environments that will allow you to create separate "environments" for each version of Python.  Virtual environments more or less work by handling all the path specification after you activate them, alllowing you to just type `python myfile.py` without worrying about conflicting dependencies or knowing the full path to a specific version of python.

[Click here for an excellent guide to getting started with Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) or [[here]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for the Python3 official documentation.

If you do not have access to the nodes and you're running this using PySpark, you can specify the [Python version in your `spark-env.sh`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables):

Spark_Install_Dir/conf/spark-env.sh:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON = /full/path/to/python_executable/eg/python2.7
```

Comment: actually I am working on hadoop cluster and I don't have access to DataNodes, So I cannot use virtaul env.

Comment: I have already tried your first suggestion with shebang but it doesn't work. Actually, I am launching spark application not just a python file so I cannot do your second suggestion

Comment: @user4851438 Ah, sorry about that - check up the update -- you can use a shell script to modify which python is used when running submitted scripts.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: this doesnt work for me either. Still looking for a solution after a month.