# python module not accessible from EMR notebook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am using an EMR notebook attached to my cluster for some experimentation purposes. I needed to install some python modules for testing, specifically spacy and it's data module en_core_web_sm.

I ssh'ed into the master and core nodes and downloaded the modules individually. However I am not able to import from the my EMR notebook. I get the following error :

```
An error was encountered:
No module named 'spacy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
```

I know there is a way to install them just for the scope of EMR notebook, but this wouldn't suffice in a production scenario, so please avoid answers which suggest notebook installing as mentioned in this guide : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/

Please let me know if I am missing some setup steps. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing the bootstrap script to use sudo instead of --user. (You could also manually change run the scripts below)

Before I was running

```
pip3 install spacy --user
python3 -m spacy download en --user
```

I changed that script to

```
sudo pip3 install spacy
sudo python3 -m spacy download en
```

To verify this solution quickly issue the following commands from your EMR notebook (to compare before and after)

```
sc.list_packages()
```

You should see an output similar to this

```
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
Package                    Version   
-------------------------- ----------
beautifulsoup4             4.9.0     
blis                       0.4.1     
boto                       2.49.0    
catalogue                  1.0.0     
certifi                    2020.4.5.2
chardet                    3.0.4     
cymem                      2.0.3     
en-core-web-sm             2.3.0     
idna                       2.9       
importlib-metadata         1.6.1     
jmespath                   0.9.5     
lxml                       4.5.0     
murmurhash                 1.0.2     
mysqlclient                1.4.2     
nltk                       3.4.5     
nose                       1.3.4     
numpy                      1.16.5    
pip                        9.0.1     
plac                       1.1.3     
preshed                    3.0.2     
py-dateutil                2.2       
python37-sagemaker-pyspark 1.3.0     
pytz                       2019.3    
PyYAML                     5.3.1     
requests                   2.24.0    
setuptools                 28.8.0    
six                        1.13.0    
soupsieve                  1.9.5     
spacy                      2.3.0     
srsly                      1.0.2     
thinc                      7.4.1     
tqdm                       4.46.1    
urllib3                    1.25.9    
wasabi                     0.6.0     
wheel                      0.29.0    
windmill                   1.6       
zipp                       3.1.0
```

This is not the best possible solution IMO, since the first warning that gets displayed after using sudo is

```
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
```

If anyone has a better solution please free to post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bootstraps to install additional modules while creating your EMR
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why I am not able to access modules which I've manually installed on the cluster. (The EMR bootstrap script would run exactly the same commands I think)

Comment: Are you sure that the old instances were not terminated and new ones were not  added to your EMR?

Comment: No I didn't terminate any instances. This a running cluster and all instances are unchanged.

Comment: Can you try importing your module in python shell on each node to make sure it's installed properly?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried opening up the python3 shell and the import command works on master and cores

Comment: I am not sure how to do that on an EMR notebook. I tried submitted the script directly to the master node of the EMR cluster using this command :

 [hadoop@ip-10-0-1-162 ~]$ spark-submit E2ECompleteTest.py --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster

I followed this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972565/how-to-specify-the-version-of-python-for-spark-submit-to-use

and this documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/  .    Look at this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512577/how-to-set-jupyter-notebook-to-python3-instead-of-python2-7-in-aws-emr

Comment: Hey Srikanth, I was able to solve this problem as mentioned in my answer below. I didn't get a chance to try your solution but I'll give it a go. Thanks for your patience and persistence!